# Do we need a physical phone to start developing on IOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I've decided to start the development of the IOS version of my react native app recently. The problem is that I do not have any physical Iphone in my possession and after my subscription to the apple developer program I can see those kind of messages in xcode

[image: xcode general section]

[image: xcode capabilities section]

How can I go through that problem since I do not have any iphone with a valid UDID to provide on https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/device/iphone/landing

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue here is that your code signing is set to "iOS Developer" and so it is looking for your development devices and finding nothing. Instead, you can change this to "iOS Distribution" which will hopefully fix this issue. Go to your app in Xcode, select the project and then:

```
Build Settings -> Signing -> Code Signing Identity
```

Switch from "iOS Developer" to "iOS Distribution". Hopefully this will fix your issue.

Comment: In the build settings section, under the code signing section I've set all the code signing identity values to "IOS Distribution" but now in the general section the error message status is :`MixitMusic has conflicting provisioning settings.
MixitMusic is automatically signed for development, but a conflicting code signing identity iPhone Distribution has been manually specified. Set the code signing identity value to "iPhone Developer" in the build settings editor, or switch to manual signing in the project editor.`

Comment: You're absolutely right, just tried it for myself. This is because it is using a development provisioning profile, but you have now told it to build for production. You will find, as I have, that your simulator will work fine and the error won't stop you working. Should you want to remove this, turn off automatic signing, and create your distribution profile on developer.apple.com, and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Absolutely as some of the features you can only test in real device

1. Apple Push notifications
2. Mail Composer
3. Camera
4. VOIP/GSM Call & APNS Background Services
5. Location